# Bash empty string comparison behavior

Tags: bash

```
$ [ $(echo) = $(echo) ]
$ echo $?
0
$ [ $(echo) != $(echo) ]
$ echo $?
0
```

Is this a bug?

P.S. I noticed this while trying to test if a string was empty; it appears I can use `test -z` for that purpose, but still am curious about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug.

You did not quote the command substitution, so it was expanded into nothing (instead of remaining an empty string). The tests ran are actually:

```
[ = ]
[ != ]
```

With a single argument, `[ ]` tests whether the argument is not an empty string, and indeed neither `=` nor `!=` are empty strings.

## Use quoting

(unless you need the effects of unquoted expansion, which you likely won't)

```
[ "$(echo)" = "" ] # $? = 0
[ "$(echo)" != "" ] # $? = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `[ $(echo) != $(echo) ]` *without quoting*, it's equivalent to `[ != ]`

Now, `man bash` says under `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` that the behavior of the `[ ... ]` test depends on the number of arguments as follows:

> ```
>           0 arguments
>                  The expression is false.
>           1 argument
>                  The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.
> ```

So since the *string* `!=` is not null, the test is `TRUE`.

If you quote the arguments, you will get the expected behaviour:

```
$ [ "$(echo)" != "$(echo)" ]
$ echo $?
1
$ [ "$(echo)" = "$(echo)" ]
$ echo $?
0
```

because you are now giving it 3 arguments:

> ```
>   3 arguments
>          The following conditions are applied in the order listed.
>          If the second argument is one of the  binary  conditional
>          operators listed above under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, the
>          result of the expression is the result of the binary test
>          using  the first and third arguments as operands.  The -a
>          and -o operators are  considered  binary  operators  when
>          there  are  three arguments.  If the first argument is !,
>          the value is the negation of the two-argument test  using
>          the second and third arguments.  If the first argument is
>          exactly ( and the third argument is exactly ), the result
>          is  the one-argument test of the second argument.  Other‐
>          wise, the expression is false.
> ```