# Bash issue with arguments

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, gnome-terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/john

name="kate"

if [ -d $dir ] && [ -n $name ]; then

    echo "The name exists and the folder $dir exists."

else

    echo "Fail"

fi
```

I just execute this command and it didn't work at all. This command should return true only if both tests succeeded otherwise, it will fail. But nothing fails.

Why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is not necessary to check both dir and name just check if the file/name exists. `-n` checks for non-empty variable you probably want `-f`

Comment: which value should I assign to the "name" variable in order to make it "Fail"?

Comment: `if [ -f "$dir/$name" ]; then` (pure logic, if the file exists the dir have to exist too)

Comment: Thanks! I understood!

Comment: If `$name` is the empty string, then `[ -n $name ]` will evaluate true whereas `[ -n "$name" ]` will evaluate false. This is one of the cases where quoting is essential.

Comment: @steeldriver oh, that makes sense. I do know that it's so essential to use quotes somehow, but didn't pay a lot attention in this case. I still cannot totally understand why it made a sense of usage the quotes over here.

Comment: This as posted should work. To see what is going on during execution, run your script like this `sh -x scriptfile` and make sure you make the file executable first by running `chmod +x scriptfile` first

Comment: @J.Doe I have added an answer with brief explanation below - I'm searching for a previous answer which iirc explained it better

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. Sorry, but I downvoted because of the totally generic and meaningless title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me also give this a shot. The existing answer has it right, but since this is a Bash question, may I suggest using a Bashism?

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Using $HOME so it should exist whenever someone tests this code
# btw: dir is not the best name here ... (shadows /bin/dir from coreutils)
dir=$HOME
name="kate"

if [[ -d $dir ]] && [[ -n $name ]]; then
    echo "The name exists and the folder $dir exists."
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

You can see the inline commentary. I also removed the extra empty lines.

Main point is that I am using `[[` instead of `[` (and the respective counterpart `]]` instead of `]`).

For reference you may want to read the output of `help [` and `help [[`. In short the `[[` is an extended version which also provides regular expression support and is smarter in many other cases. I have made it a habit to use that instead of `[ expression ]` whenever I am allowed to forego compatibility with plain POSIX shell.

I am not sure that this can correctly be referred to as a "bug" (defect). I would hold that this is likely owed to backward compatibility. But I am not a 100% certain if the supposed "buggy" behavior was actually codified in the POSIX standard or so.

---

As further points:

1. if you want to check whether a user exists you should use `id` or `getent passwd` (whichever is available and more suitable to what you want). You *could* also use `eval echo ~$name` (if `$name` contains the username). And no, this is not a mistake. The `~username` expands to the home directory of said user, but only through the help of `eval` (or tab completion on the prompt).
2. you may rather want to base your findings about a given user(name) on `getent passwd` output rather than hardcoding assumptions such as that home directories *ought* to be in `/home` ...

But that's just my two additional cents ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

If `$dir` or `$name` are empty, then `[ -d $dir ]` or `[ -n $name ]` will evaluate TRUE, because they become `[ -d ]` and `[ -n ]` which test for non-zero length of literal strings `-d` and `-n`, as discussed in more detail in answers to this related question:

- [bash compare empty strings bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056950/bash-compare-empty-strings-bug/1056957)

Ex.

```
$ name=
$ [ -n $name ] && echo true || echo false
true

$ [ -n "$name" ] && echo true || echo false
false
```

So you should use

```
if [ -d "$dir" ] && [ -n "$name" ]; then
```

**However** if you want to know whether the *file* `$dir/$name` exists, you should do that with a single test

```
if [ -f "$dir/$name" ]
```

as noted in [@bac0n's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228843/maybe-the-easiest-question?noredirect=1#comment2068126_1228843)

Comment: Thank you for explanation.

Comment: `#! /bin/bash
dir=/home/
name="kate"
if [ -d "$dir/$name" ]; then
    echo "The name exists and the folder $dir$name exists."

else

    echo "no username"

fi`

Because I was trying to find is there any valid user in PC, the most appropriate solution is above, isn't it?

Comment: @J.Doe the existence of home directory `/home/kate` corresponding to username `kate` is only really a *convention* - a more technically correct solution would be testing the exit status of `getent passwd kate`