# Checking if file=$1 exist

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have problem with this task. Could you check if it was done correctly?

Check if a file with provided parameter exist, if not please create this file

```
    file=$1 

    if [ -f $file ]
    then
      echo "File $file exist"
    else
      echo "File $file doesn't exist and will be created"
      touch 1.txt
```

What does file=$1 mean? 1 - Is it file name? When I launch this script there are popping information: "File exist" but I don't have any file named like this.

Comment: This question isn't related to Ubuntu, try Stackoverlow.

Comment: You need quotes around `$file` to stop your test evaluating TRUE when `$1` is empty - for the same reasons as discussed here [Bash issue with arguments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228843/bash-issue-with-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file=$1` assigns variable `file` the first paramter of your script.

If you run you script like  this:

```
script.sh blablabla
```

Then `blablabla` will be the file name that the script will check if it exists.

The last line seems wrong to me. It should be

```
touch $1
```

if I understand the script.